# How to loop through questions

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid, jsfiddle

I'm trying to create a simple addition quiz where the user adds two numbers, presses "Submit," and is then presented with the next problem. I'm trying to use arrays to put together the problem because I'm going to have to (eventually) store the user's answers and compare them with the correct answers. For now though, I'd be really happy to just get the next problem to show up when the user presses "Submit."

http://jsfiddle.net/ZwwLh/4

HTML:

```
<form>
<table id="addProblem" width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="1" align="right"><input id="carryOver"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" id="firstNum">48</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>+</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" id="secondNum">16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><hr id="sepLine"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right"><input id="userAnswer" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><button onclick="checkAnswer()">Submit</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var numOne = [48,39,16,43,37,23,44,13,37,28,48,16];    // first number in addition problem
var numTwo = [16,22,25,18,46,49,18,39,25,17,9,28];     // second number in addition problem

var i = 0;

function checkAnswer() {
    // assigns guessed number to variable
    var guess = Number(document.getElementById('userAnswer').value);

    if (guess == numOne[i]+numTwo[i]) {
        if(confirm("Correct!")) {
            // next question
            i++;
            document.getElementById('firstNum').innerHTML=numOne[i];
            document.getElementById('secondNum').innerHTML=numTwo[i];
        }
    } else {
        if(confirm("Incorrect")) {
            // next question
            i++;
            document.getElementById('firstNum').innerHTML=numOne[i];
            document.getElementById('secondNum').innerHTML=numTwo[i];           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementById takes a string as the parameter, so you need to do this:

```
document.getElementById('numOne').innerHTML=numOne[i]; //notice the single quotes around numOne
```

you might want to rename your numOne and numTwo variables as they might confuse you with the IDs you are using for the TDs.

Comment: I added the single quotes, and it appears to work for a moment before the old numbers are displayed again. :/

Comment: This is what I get when I upload your code: http://theyellowparachute.com/test/MathWorksheet/

Comment: makes sense. as of IE 8, if you put a button inside a form, the default behavior is to submit/post, which causes a reload.  you can either not put it inside a form or possibly use `<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="checkAnswer()" />` . for completeness, here is a reference to what I was talking about: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp . form tags are specifically used to post input back to the server and it appears you are not doing that, so feel free to get rid of it.

Comment: Using <input> instead of <button> worked wonderfully! The only thing is that now the previously input answer remains when the new problem displays. Is there anyway to reset the input field back to being blank for each new problem? Also, I'm working towards creating a page after submitting the last problem, which will display all of the problems and the user's answers. Is it inappropriate to use form tags for this purpose?

Comment: Check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/hPE42/1/ I cleaned up the code a little, because you had duplication of setting the next answer and I also showed you how to reset the userAnswer to blank. As for the form tag, it depends on what you want to pass back to your server. If you want to pass back information, then a form tag is acceptable. And the solution to that depends on what/if any server framework you are using (php,asp,...).

Answer (score 0):

```
    var numOne = [48, 39, 16, 43, 37, 23, 44, 13, 37, 28, 48, 16];
    var numTwo = [16, 22, 25, 18, 46, 49, 18, 39, 25, 17, 9, 28];
    var i = 0;

    window.onload = function () {
        a = document.getElementById('firstNum').innerHTML = numOne[i];
        b = document.getElementById('secondNum').innerHTML = numTwo[i];
        i++;
    }
    function clicked() {
        var c = a + b;
        var guess = document.getElementById('userAnswer').value;
        if (guess == c) {
            alert('correct');
        }
        else {
            alert('incorrect');
        }
        a = document.getElementById('firstNum').innerHTML = numOne[i];
        b = document.getElementById('secondNum').innerHTML = numTwo[i];
        i++;
    }


<form>
    <table id="addProblem" width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2" align="right" id="firstNum"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>+</td>
            <td colspan="2" align="right" id="secondNum"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <hr id="sepLine">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
                <input type="text" id="userAnswer" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="button" onclick="clicked();" value="Submit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**or you can use a multidimensional array**

```
    //var numOne = [48, 39, 16, 43, 37, 23, 44, 13, 37, 28, 48, 16];
    //var numTwo = [16, 22, 25, 18, 46, 49, 18, 39, 25, 17, 9, 28];
    score = 0;
    var md = [
        [48, 16],
        [39, 22],
        [16, 25],
        [43, 18],
        [37, 46],
        [23, 49],
        [44, 18],
        [13, 39],
        [37, 25],
        [28, 17],
        [48, 9],
        [16, 28],
    ];
    var i = 0;
    var j = 1;
    var z = 0;
    window.onload = function () {
        a = document.getElementById('firstNum').innerHTML = md[i][i];
        b = document.getElementById('secondNum').innerHTML = md[i][j];
        i++;
    }
    function clicked() {
        var c = a + b;
        var guess = document.getElementById('userAnswer').value;
        if (guess == c) {
            alert('correct');
            score++;
            document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'Number right: ' + score;
        }
        else {
            alert('incorrect');
        }
        a = document.getElementById('firstNum').innerHTML = md[i][z];
        b = document.getElementById('secondNum').innerHTML = md[i][j];
        i++;
    }
```